# Autofilter numeric values with ActiveX textbox and Autofiltered column?

Tags: excel, activex, autofilter, vba

I thought this would be easier but it's eating my lunch. I have a master Excel list with many columns, some text, some numeric, and one with a leading letter followed by two numbers. They are autofilter and also have an activeX textbox. I've linked the Textbox to VBA and have all String-based columns up and working flawlessly. It goes as follows:

```
Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
Range("$E$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Visibledropdown:=True    'Leave the drop down arrows on
Range("$E$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*" & TextBox4 & "*"
End Sub
```

Now let's say that exact column was filled with numbers instead. How would I do this? It filters out numeric values with the code above. Has anyone solved for this using this setup? I've been looking for hours today here and elsewhere, just can't find the right solution to this specific problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this was really easy, just change the value of Criteria1 to Textbox4, that's all:

```
Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
  Range("$E$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Visibledropdown:=True    'Leave the drop down arrows on
Range("$E$1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=TextBox4
End Sub
```